Ubuntu stuck while switching keyboard layout
Description
My Ubuntu 24.04 with fcitx would freeze when the keyboard layout is switched to German and back to English. Switching to and from tty3 sometimes solve the issue, but not always. Everything except the mouse is freezed. I can switch tty, but cannot call out terminal or use Alt+F2 to launch commands. Switching the layout settings in settings also causes the computer to freeze.
log
Here is my journalctl output:
Dec 28 20:56:38 john-doe-ubuntu google-chrome.desktop[9291]: [9284:9313:1228/205638.861414:ERROR:registration_request.cc(291)] Registration response error message: DEPRECATED_ENDPOINT
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "52"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event14 - Video Bus: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "42"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event13 - Video Bus: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "51"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event4  - ELAN07C6:00 04F3:32C7 Mouse: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "50"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event5  - ELAN07C6:00 04F3:32C7 Touchpad: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "113"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event6  - Intel HID events: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event7  - Intel HID 5 button array: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (**) Option "fd" "47"
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) event8  - HP WMI hotkeys: device removed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) systemd-logind: drop master for 226:1
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu gsd-media-keys[4850]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu gsd-media-keys[4850]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu gsd-media-keys[4850]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu gsd-media-keys[4850]: Unable to get default sink
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu gsd-media-keys[4850]: Unable to get default source
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu gsd-media-keys[4850]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu gsd-media-keys[4850]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu gsd-media-keys[4850]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
Dec 28 20:56:40 john-doe-ubuntu bluetoothd[1582]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.370 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
Dec 28 20:56:41 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Dec 28 20:56:41 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:78
Dec 28 20:56:41 john-doe-ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4210]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72

The fcitx-diagnosis reads:
2.  `lsb_release -a`:

        Distributor ID: Ubuntu
        Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
        Release:    24.04
        Codename:   noble

3.  `lsb_release -d`:

        Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

4.  `/etc/lsb-release`:

        DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
        DISTRIB_RELEASE=24.04
        DISTRIB_CODENAME=noble
        DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"

5.  `/etc/os-release`:

        PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"
        NAME="Ubuntu"
        VERSION_ID="24.04"
        VERSION="24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
        VERSION_CODENAME=noble
        ID=ubuntu
        ID_LIKE=debian
        HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
        SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
        BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
        PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
        UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble
        LOGO=ubuntu-logo

6.  Desktop Environment:

    Desktop environment is `gnome3`.

7.  Bash Version:

        BASH_VERSION='5.2.21(1)-release'

# Environment:
1.  DISPLAY:

        DISPLAY=':1'

2.  Keyboard Layout:

    1.  `setxkbmap`:

            xkb_keymap {
                xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
                xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
                xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
                xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+de:2+us:3+inet(evdev)"   };
                xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
            };

    2.  `xprop`:

            _XKB_RULES_NAMES(STRING) = "evdev", "pc105+inet", "us,de,us", ",,", ""

3.  Locale:

    1.  All locale:

            C
            C.utf8
            de_AT.utf8
            de_BE.utf8
            de_CH.utf8
            de_DE.utf8
            de_IT.utf8
            de_LI.utf8
            de_LU.utf8
            en_AG
            en_AG.utf8
            en_AU.utf8
            en_BW.utf8
            en_CA.utf8
            en_DK.utf8
            en_GB.utf8
            en_HK.utf8
            en_IE.utf8
            en_IL
            en_IL.utf8
            en_IN
            en_IN.utf8
            en_NG
            en_NG.utf8
            en_NZ.utf8
            en_PH.utf8
            en_SG.utf8
            en_US.utf8
            en_ZA.utf8
            en_ZM
            en_ZM.utf8
            en_ZW.utf8
            POSIX

    2.  Current locale:

            LANG=en_US.UTF-8
            LANGUAGE=en
            LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
            LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
            LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
            LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
            LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
            LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
            LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
            LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
            LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
            LC_ALL=

4.  Directories:

    1.  Home:

            /home/danny-wenjue-zhang

    2.  `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}`:

        Environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set to `/home/danny-wenjue-zhang/.config`.

        Current value of `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is `~/.config` (`/home/danny-wenjue-zhang/.config`).

    3.  Fcitx Settings Directory:

        Current fcitx settings directory is `~/.config/fcitx` (`/home/danny-wenjue-zhang/.config/fcitx`).

5.  Current user:

    The script is run as danny-wenjue-zhang (1000).

# Fcitx State:
1.  executable:

    Found fcitx at `/usr/bin/fcitx`.

2.  version:

    Fcitx version: `4.2.9.9`

3.  process:

    Found 2 fcitx processes:

           4361 fcitx
           4373 fcitx-dbus-watc

4.  `fcitx-remote`:

    `fcitx-remote` works properly.

5.  DBus interface:

    Using `dbus-send` to check dbus.

    Owner of DBus name `org.fcitx.Fcitx` is `:1.18`.

    PID of DBus name `org.fcitx.Fcitx` owner is `4361`.

# Fcitx Configure UI:
1.  Config Tool Wrapper:

    Found fcitx-configtool at `/usr/bin/fcitx-configtool`.

2.  Config GUI for gtk2:

    **Config GUI for gtk2 not found.**

3.  Config GUI for gtk3:

    Found `fcitx-config-gtk3` at `/usr/bin/fcitx-config-gtk3`.

4.  Config GUI for kde:

    **`kcmshell4` not found.**

# Frontends setup:
## Xim:
1.  `${XMODIFIERS}`:

    Environment variable XMODIFIERS is set to "@im=fcitx" correctly.
    Xim Server Name from Environment variable is fcitx.

2.  XIM_SERVERS on root window:

    Xim server name is the same with that set in the environment variable.

## Qt:
1.  qt4 - `${QT4_IM_MODULE}`:

    Environment variable QT_IM_MODULE is set to "fcitx" correctly.

2.  qt5 - `${QT_IM_MODULE}`:

    Environment variable QT_IM_MODULE is set to "fcitx" correctly.

3.  Qt IM module files:

    Found fcitx im module for Qt5: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libfcitxplatforminputcontextplugin.so`.
    Found fcitx im module for Qt5: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libfcitxplatforminputcontextplugin-qt6.so`.
    Found fcitx qt module: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fcitx/qt/libfcitx-quickphrase-editor5.so`.
    **Cannot find fcitx input method module for Qt4.**

## Gtk:
1.  gtk - `${GTK_IM_MODULE}`:

    Environment variable GTK_IM_MODULE is set to "fcitx" correctly.

2.  `gtk-query-immodules`:

    1.  gtk 2:

        **Cannot find `gtk-query-immodules` for gtk 2**

        **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 2.**

    2.  gtk 3:

        **Cannot find `gtk-query-immodules` for gtk 3**

        **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 3.**

3.  Gtk IM module cache:

    1.  gtk 2:

        Found immodules cache for gtk `2.24.33` at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache`.
        Version Line:

            # Created by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk2.0-0t64/gtk-query-immodules-2.0 from gtk+-2.24.33

        Found fcitx im modules for gtk `2.24.33`.

            "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-fcitx.so" 
            "fcitx" "Fcitx (Flexible Input Method Framework)" "fcitx" "/usr/share/locale" "ja:ko:zh:*" 

    2.  gtk 3:

        Found immodules cache for gtk `3.24.41` at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache`.
        Version Line:

            # Created by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0t64/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 from gtk+-3.24.41

        Found fcitx im modules for gtk `3.24.41`.

            "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-fcitx.so" 
            "fcitx" "Fcitx (Flexible Input Method Framework)" "fcitx" "/usr/share/locale" "ja:ko:zh:*" 

4.  Gtk IM module files:

    1.  gtk 2:

        All found Gtk 2 immodule files exist.

    2.  gtk 3:

        All found Gtk 3 immodule files exist.

# Configuration:
## Fcitx Addons:
1.  Addon Config Dir:

    Found fcitx addon config directory: `/usr/share/fcitx/addon`.

2.  Addon List:

    1.  Found 26 enabled addons:

            fcitx-autoeng
            fcitx-chttrans
            fcitx-classic-ui
            fcitx-clipboard
            fcitx-dbus
            fcitx-fullwidth-char
            fcitx-imselector
            fcitx-ipc
            fcitx-ipcportal
            fcitx-keyboard
            fcitx-kimpanel-ui
            fcitx-lua
            fcitx-notificationitem
            fcitx-punc
            fcitx-quickphrase
            fcitx-remote
            fcitx-sogoupinyin
            fcitx-sogoupinyinhdm
            fcitx-sogoupinyinhxm
            fcitx-spell
            fcitx-unicode
            fcitx-vk
            fcitx-x11
            fcitx-xim
            fcitx-xkb
            fcitx-xkbdbus

    2.  Found 1 disabled addons:

            fcitx-freedesktop-notify

3.  Addon Libraries:

    All libraries for all addons are found.

4.  User Interface:

    Found 2 enabled user interface addons:

        fcitx-classic-ui
        fcitx-kimpanel-ui

## Input Methods:
1.  Found 3 enabled input methods:

        fcitx-keyboard-us
        sogoupinyin
        fcitx-keyboard-cn

2.  Default input methods:

    You have a keyboard input method "fcitx-keyboard-us" correctly added as your default input method.

# Log:
1.  `date`:

        Sat Dec 28 08:51:47 PM CST 2024

2.  `~/.config/fcitx/log/`:

        total 0

3.  `~/.config/fcitx/log/crash.log`:

    `~/.config/fcitx/log/crash.log` not found.

Omitted first session to protect privacy.

Update: By following another post, I tried switch to tty3 back. It is weird that it sometimes work. After I tried to reinstall fcitx, things get worse that it would freeze when reboot randomly, and the same log appears again.

Reinstalling ubuntu-desktop solved the issue.
